# Flutter on VS Code run stuck on "Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk..."

Tags: flutter

When I run my application using the VS Code Run and Debug, The app is installed on my device and is stuck on a white screen. Meanwhile in the editor, the VS Code notification is stuck on "Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk..."

I've tried to run different flutter apps on the physical device but was still met with the same error. I've also tried to run the flutter example increment app, but to no avail. I also uninstalled and reinstalled the flutter sdk from the stable GitHub branch but that also did not work. I've also tried solutions from about 22 other questions with similar problems.

However, when I use flutter run from the command line, the app installs and launches on my phone, however, I'm unable to use the Flutter DevTools Inspector.

P.S I've been able to debug flutter apps on the device with the Flutter DevTools in the past.

Comment: What is your default shell in vscode?

Comment: @Riz-waan I use powershell

Comment: on both vscode and commandline?

Comment: @Riz-waan yes, on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Flutter v1.20.2, this problem has been resolved. The linked GitHub issue is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57766) if you disagree about the problem being solved.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to end the flutter, dart and flutter processes. So in terminal do this:

```
killall adb
killall dart
killall flutter
```

Then reload vscode